# Deep learning: representation learning or classification?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, feature-selection, graphical-model, deep-learning

For classification, I have often heard about deep learning / deep neural networks as a form of representation learning. I am confused as to what "representation learning" means in this context. Which of the following is the case?

1) The output layer of the network gives a feature vector, with one output node per vector element. This feature vector is then passed into a classifier. As such, the output layer is learning a better "representation" of the data than the original input layer, which means it is more suitable when put through a classifier.

2) The output layer of the network gives a classification score for each class, with one output node per class. The score for each class is then the value of the respective output node.

Number 2 is the way I have seen artificial neural networks being used in the past, but number 1 is learning "representations". Which is the one used in deep learning?

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment since I'm far from an expert but I believe that in a deep neural network the earlier hidden layers learn a representation and then the final layers do the classification. The wikipedia page on deep learning seems to corroborate this. See the opening couple of paragraphs and the section specific to deep neural networks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning#Deep_neural_networks

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion: *it's both*. It's referenced many times in the highly cited article on convolutional neural networks [Gradient-Based Learning Applied to Document Recognition](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf) by Yann LeCun, Yoshua Bengio, Leon Bottou and Patrick Haffner.

The idea is that it is quite hard to hand-design a rich and complex feature hierarchy. For low level features, we see that conv-nets learn edges or color blobs. This makes intuitive sense and from early computer vision methods, we have some good quality hand-crafted edge feature detectors. But how to compose these features to form richer and more complex features is not a simple task to do by hand. And now imagine trying to design a 10-level feature hierarchy.

Instead what you can do is tie the representation learning and classification tasks together, as is done in deep networks. Now we allow the data to drive the feature learning mechanism.

Deep architectures are designed to learn a hierarchy of features from the data as opposed to ad-hoc hand-crafted features designed by humans. Most importantly, the features will be learned with the explicit objective of learning a hierarchical feature representation which obtains low error on a given loss function which measures the performance of our deep net. A priori, given some hand-crafted features, one does not know how good these features are for the task at hand. In this manner, desired high performance on the task at hand will drive the quality of the learned features and they become inextricably linked together.

This end-to-end training/classification pipeline has been a big idea when it comes to designing computer vision architectures.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's basically representation learning followed by classification at the end.

Consider an Image Classification Problem.

-> We have to find some way(some characteristics/attributes) to tell if the image is a dog or a cat (which in our terms is referred to as **features**)

-> Extracting the useful features is the most important part of machine learning & we call this extraction of features as representation learning (i.e basically extracting the useful features from the raw data).

-> For the given example (dog vs cat), it's difficult for the model to get hold of the most important features in the first glance itself (i.e we can't use the pixel information and extract the target features directly).

-> Which leads us to the deep learning concept, where we look to extract the features in stages/layers (by using the previous layers information). In our problem, it would look something like:

1. Layer 1 - learns about the edges (which gives an outline of the object in the image)
2. Layer 2 - learns about the corners & contours (which gives information about the shapes in image)
3. Layer 3 - learn about the object parts (legs, nose etc)
4. Final Layer - which basically tries to classify the data/features (that it learned from the previous layers)